# try to fetch information of specific foreign key

Tags: php, sql

i am new in php and mysql.
I am trying to fetch information from one of my table.
Just give you the information about my table.
Name of my table is `leave`.it contaning one foreign key namely `leaveId`.

```
    lid     empname     username    nod     date     reason  action leaveID 
    ===     =======     ========    ===     =====    ======  ====== =======
     1      Maxwell       max        1       2012     Null   Denied    3
     2      Ponting      punter      1       2011     Null   Denied    4
     3      Ponting      punter      2       2011     xam    Accepted  4
     4      Taylor       tayl        1       2011     Null   Accepted  1
```

now as example is there  any sql query to retrieve only the information of `Pointing` whom `leaveId` is 4. I wrote the following query..

```
$leave = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `leave` where leaveID = $user ");
```

but it only return the 2nd row associated with the number 4
`leaveId` where it should return the both 2nd and 3rd row,isn't it?? .
Actually i am not sure...if it is wrong then give me the right answer to(as example) how can i fetch the information of  ponting  whom leaveID is 4.

Comment: That SQL query is correct, what PHP code are you using afterwards to process the results? Probably that's your problem.

Comment: you are passing $user as 4 in leaveID=$user? if so, there should be two rows. how are you validating that there is just one row in output? have you tried running this query in an sql editor?

Comment: it should return them both, but you need to iterate through the result set. So you need to call `mysql_fetch_row` twice to get both rows!

Comment: @raihanveer - out of curiosity, why are you using mysql_* functions? Is there some kind of popular tutorial that tells people to use those?

Answer (score 1):

you need to get your rows with a while loop

```
$leave = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `leave` where leaveID = $user ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($leave, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf(" ID:", $row[0], "empname ", $row[1]);  
}
```